# Cannot get query Params on routerOnActivate

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

Im having problems trying to get query params using the new Route library.

**VERSION**
2.0.0-rc.1

**Problem**

```
routerOnActivate(curr:RouteSegment, prev?:RouteSegment, currTree?:RouteTree, prevTree?:RouteTree):void {
  console.log(curr.getParam("test"));
}
```

**Always prints undefined**

**Another problem is that my url gets "reseted" everytime (Thats why i think curr.getParam("test") returns undefined)**

Here is my App Component and My Home Component :

**APP COMPONENT**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Router } from '@angular/router'
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

@Component({
    selector    : 'my-app',
    template : '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives  : [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
    providers   : [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS ]
})
@Routes([
    {
        path : '/',
        component : HomeComponent
    }
])
export class AppComponent {
    constructor (private _router : Router) {
    }
}
```

**HOME COMPONENT**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, OnActivate, RouteSegment } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    template: '<h3>THIS IS HOME</h3>'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnActivate{
    constructor(private _router : Router) {
        console.log('Called');
    }

    routerOnActivate(curr:RouteSegment):void {
        console.log(curr.getParam("test"));
    }
}
```

**TEST URL**

localhost:3000/?test=helloworld --> Changes to(problem) localhost:3000

Can somebody help?

Comment: The URL "localhost:3000/?test=helloworld" is a query string, not a route. It should be this "localhost:3000/test/helloworld" instead.

Comment: My parameters in a real application are optional. Thats why im using query strings.

I think i have found the problem. The new route library appears to only support Matrix URL notation. So using localhost:3000/;test=helloworld instead of "?" and "&" should fix the problem. I really didnt like this "new"(not new) notation since almost every site use ? and &

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks good, the only problem is that as per [official Angular 2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#matrix-parameters):

> The query string parameters are no longer separated by "?" and "&". They are separated by semicolons (;) This is [matrix URL notation](https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html) — something we may not have seen before. Matrix URL notation is an idea first floated in a 1996 proposal and although it never made it into the HTML standard, it is legal and it became popular among browser routing systems as a way to isolate parameters belonging to parent and child routes. The Angular Component Router is such a system.

So you can get the value of optional parameter (test) from current RouteSegment by change your address from

localhost:3000/?test=helloworld

to

***localhost:3000/;test=helloworld***