# Angular 2 rc 1 router - rewrites url

Tags: routes, angular

After updating to rc 1 routing, my application doesn't work when url has query string parameters.

Here is how the routes are defined in the app component:

```
import {Component,  OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Routes, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
@Component({ selector: 'my-app',
    providers:[ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
    template: 
    `
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
    , directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@Routes([
    {path:'/designer',              component: MainComponent},
    {path:'/designer/designs/:id',   component: SharedDesignComponent}
])
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {

constructor(private router: Router){}

ngOnInit() {  
    console.log("appComponent: Initialized");
 }

ngOnDestroy() {  } 
}
```

And here is the Main Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input, ChangeDetectorRef} from "@angular/core";
import {OnActivate, Router, RouteSegment} from "@angular/router";
@Component({
    selector: "my-main",
    templateUrl: "main.html"
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router){}
    routerOnActivate(curr: RouteSegment) : void { 
        let id = curr.getParam("designId");
    }
    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

So the problem is when I have the url like this, http://localhost:49191/designer?designId=100, it calls the main component correctly and the routerOnActivate is called too. But inside it, I don't get id. And as soon as the ngOnInit is called, the url is changed to http://localhost:49191/designer without the query string parameter.

How do I retain the url? And not let it change by the router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access your MainComponent like this:

```
http://localhost:49191/designer;designId=100
```

Notice how I replaced `?` with `;`

And everything should work fine.

Basically the query string parameters are no longer separated by "?" and "&". They are separated by semicolons (**;**). This is called [Matrix URL notation](https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html) which is the way [Angular 2 RC1 Router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#matrix-parameters) works based on.

Please see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144323/cannot-get-query-params-on-routeronactivate/37146445#37146445) for more info.

Comment: It didn't work like this because my app resides in an MVC app. It gives me page not found error. But if I try it like this with an extra '/#/' http://localhost:49191/designer/#/;designId=100 it calls the app correctly but again I have the same problem. id is undefined and url gets rewritten after routerOnActivate() call

Comment: I accept this as an answer if the application runs by itself. For my application that runs inside an MVC app, I added routes to mvc to get to my application like this: http://localhost:49191/designer/100                                   And that worked fine with the above code.